# File location from OneNote Notebook in SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, file, onenote

I am searching for the file location from a OneNote Notebook in SharePoint. In the Documents Library is only a internet shortcut and not the original file (.onepkg).

My Question is where is in SharePoint/OneDrive the file location from the full Notebook?

[image: Screenshot OneDrive Folder]

Answer (score 0):

The location of OneNote Notebook in our SharePoint Online environment is SiteAssets.
Example: https://****.sharepoint.com/****/SiteAssets/Forms/AllItems.aspx

Comment: The format of the Notebook file in SiteAssets is also a Internet Shortcut and has only 1KB. I am searching for the file location of the "full" Notebook.